# Is lme4:::profile.merMod() supposed to work with glmer models?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

Is lme4:::profile.merMod() supposed to work with glmer models? What about Negative Binomial models?

I have a negative binomial model that throws this error:

`Error in names(opt) <- profnames(fm, signames) : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]`

When I try and run the profile function on my model `profile(model12)` to get standard errors for my random effects.

Am I missing something or is this a problem with lme4?

I should mention that I'm using `glmer(..., family = negative.binomial(theta  = lme4:::est_theta(poissonmodel)))` not `glmer.nb()` because I had issues with the `update()` function in using `glmer.nb()`.

Comment: is this still an issue with current versions of lme4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your error with the CRAN version (1.1-8). There has been some improvement in `glmer.nb` in the most recent development version, so if you have compilation tools installed I would definitely do `devtools::install_github("lme4/lme4")` and try again.  In addition, `update()` works better with NB models now, so you might not need your workaround.

This works fine with version 1.1-9:

```
library("lme4")
m1 <- glmer.nb(TICKS~cHEIGHT+(1|BROOD),data=grouseticks)
pp <- profile(m1)
lattice::xyplot(pp)
```

Note by the way that your solution with `est_theta` only does the initial step or two of an iterative solution where the `theta` value and the other parameters are optimized in alternation ...

```
m0 <- glmer(TICKS~cHEIGHT+(1|BROOD),data=grouseticks,family=poisson)
m2 <- update(m0, 
     family = negative.binomial(theta  = lme4:::est_theta(m0)))
cbind(glmer.nb=fixef(m1),pois=fixef(m0),fakenb=fixef(m2))
##                glmer.nb        pois      fakenb
## (Intercept)  0.58573085  0.56835340  0.57759498
## cHEIGHT     -0.02520326 -0.02521386 -0.02520702
```

`profile()` works OK on this model too, at least in the devel version ...

Comment: Thank you @Ben Bolker for the suggested package update and comment on the est_theta workaround, I hadn't noticed. I'll try these out tonight and update this post.

Comment: thanks for sending the model (`glmer_nb_model12.rda`), but ... the model is messed up (by having been fitted in 1.1-8) -- you need to re-fit with 1.1-9.

Comment: I sent the updated model. The update and plot function are fixed for glmer.nb models but not the profile function.

Comment: hmm, OK, I'll take another look